# Using LaTeX, how can I make vertical phone number "tear-offs" for a poster?

Tags: latex

Using LaTeX, how can I make vertical phone number "tear-offs" for a poster?

I've searched all over for an example of this, but haven't found anything yet. I'm thinking I need to use something like the textpos package or do some table mangling, but I haven't hit gold yet.

FYI I'm using the article document class for this.

Comment: Belongs on http://tex.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rotatebox` can rotate your text.

```
\rotatebox{90}{vertical text}
```